# Eclipse: Finding superclass or interface for an overriden method

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a class that extends a supertype, and also implementing several interfaces.

And within that class, i also have an *overriden method*.

Problem is how do i **quickly find out the origin** of this method in one of the supertype or interfaces used **without having to traverse the types one by one** ?

Just like this example:

```
class HelloWorld 
    extends ParentType 
    implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB, interfaceC {

  // yes it's a overriden method, but is it from ParentType
  // or InterfaceA, or InterfaceB, or InterfaceC ?
  @Override
  public void hello() {
    // do sth here
  }

  ...
}
```

Furthemore, either the parent type or the interfaces could be **extending** other types, which might have the overriden method.

Comment: ok, and who says it's not from ParentType AND from InterfaceA, InterfaceB, InterfaceC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse displays for each overridden method a green arrow-like triangle on the left of the method's first line. When you click on that triangle, it takes you to the class/interface containing the method that your method is overriding/implementing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use keyword super.class It will help you find out from which class it is coming from.